# Show subcategories for selected parent category in search.php in Osclass

Tags: php, osclass

I am trying to figure out how can I show subcategories for selected parent category in search.php. I have code which shows subcategories of all categories, but how can I modify this code to show subcategories for only selected category?

this is my code:

```
    <?php  while(osc_has_categories()) { ?>

                                            <?php if(osc_count_subcategories() > 0) { ?>
                                            <ul>
                                                <?php while(osc_has_subcategories()) { ?>
                                                <li>
                                                <strong><a href="<?php echo osc_search_category_url() ?>"><?php echo osc_category_name(); ?></a></strong></label>
                                                </li>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                            </ul>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                    <?php } ?>
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in a loop `while(osc_has_categories())`, it allows you to use `osc_category_*` helpers.

You could do something like:

```
<?php  while(osc_has_categories()) { ?>
    <?php if(osc_category_id() === 98): ?>
        <?php if(osc_count_subcategories() > 0) { ?>
        <ul>
            <?php while(osc_has_subcategories()) { ?>
            <li>
            <strong><a href="<?php echo osc_search_category_url() ?>"><?php echo osc_category_name(); ?></a></strong>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: this is showing all categories and not sub categories of a parent category.

Comment: @jaahvicky change the category id = 98 into yours main category id in following line `<?php if(osc_category_id() === 98): ?>`